# How to increase or update the Set timeout or timeout delay while doing a mouse over in Angular 2+ / Javascript / Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

Hi i am showing a notification message in a div for 10 seconds on button click by using setTimeout().

```
const ms = 10000;
new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)).then(() => {
        this.startNotification();
 });
```

The above code will start showing a notification message upto 10 seconds. Now i would like to extends the time. (i.e) if i hover on the notification message after 5sec of notification started and i placed the mouse on the notification message for 10seconds then the timeout will need to extends total of 20 seconds . (i.e) the seconds which i hover on the message (10 sec) + origonal delay time(10 sec) totally 20 sec. i tried by searching multiple resources unable to find a exact solution.
Is it possible to extend or update the running timeout delay time in setTimeout() or debounceTime(). Eventhough i tried debounceTime it only behave like setimeout. but my need is to update the existing delaytime after it starts running.
kindly help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called debouncing. Search for debounce npms.

Comment: Thanks @bravemaster. Will check

Comment: @bravemaster is it possible to extend the timeout delay time while it's running. Kindly advise